# Pig - Get all records with invalid date format

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have some data I think may be dirty; specifically, one column that should be a date may have a few rows that aren't in the correct date format.

How, using pig, can I get all the rows from my file who do not have the proper date in this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a UDF in Python.

```
from pig_util import outputSchema
from datetime import datetime
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

@outputSchema('number:is_date')
def is_date(date):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date, date_format)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
    return 1
```

And in pig:

```
REGISTER 'myudf.py' using jython as udf
raw = load '/path/to/file.csv' 
    USING PigStorage(',') 
    AS (id:chararray, consumption_date:chararray);
modified = FOREACH raw 
    GENERATE id, consumption_month, udf.is_date(consumption_month) as is_date;
bad = FILTER modified BY is_date == 0;
dump bad;
```

Comment: You can take it one step further and turn your udf into a filter udf
(boolean for outputSchema). https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/udf.html  You'll get your list with filter alone.